# read variable value from xterm and export value in another bash file

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access, remote-x-session, remote-login

I am trying to do a remote desktop connection between Ubuntu desktop and another Ubuntu system. I want to develop an application so it is necessary to use shell command.

```
ssh -X or -Y username@server_ip
```

I know this command is for trusted and untrusted connection between two systems but here username is necessary for connection so it is necessary to ask username and password to each user for connection. 
so I have created a bash file for getting input from the user. its name myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash <br>
read -p 'Username: ' uservar
read -sp 'Password: ' passvar
sleep 10
```

and I want to use this variable value in another file. I wrote below code and file name terminal.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash<br>
xterm -e /file_path/myscript.sh
sshpass -p $passvar ssh -X $uservar@$remote_ip /usr/bin/xfce4-session
```

but this code is nor working. I want myscript.sh user input value in terminal.sh file. Can anyone suggest a solution?
thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure if the <br> is a typo because you are trying to add it here or if that is in your script. I have never seen people use HTML code in a bash script .. if that is in your code .. you may want to try it without the HTML code ... remove all the <br> in the script ... have no idea if this will help but ... it just struck me as odd

Comment: it was my typing mistake John Orion

Comment: What is not working when you run it?  You can run your script with a `-x` option so that you can see line by line how it is working.  `bash -x terminal.sh`

Comment: One other thing, you source your `myscript.sh` file, then you call it.  You only need to source the file.  Remove the second call to `xterm -e /file_path/myscript.sh`

Comment: basically, I need myscript.sh variable( uservar, passvar) value in terminal.sh file for remote desktop connection. ssh -X command will be executed.if I am typing value manually.

Comment: Let me write an answer for you.

Comment: first of all, xterm is opening and user can enter this value via xterm. after that, i want to use it for ssh connection

Comment: Just set the `xterm` line as `xterm -e 'source /file_path/myscript.sh'`.  I have no idea what the `sleep 10` is for.

Comment: I am not changing my mind. I just wrote it for your understanding.  xterm -e 'source /file_path/myscript.sh' line is not working here

Comment: I am not understanding why you need xterm to read the user input.   They will read the same.  I do not recommend that you try to pass variables between separate terminal sessions.  But, if you insist on doing it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849842/linux-bash-script-share-variable-among-terminal-windows where you will have to write the variables to a separate file, then re-source the file again.  You might be looking at making your script more complicated than it should be.

Comment: here, i am using xterm because it running on lightdm login manager display and which is asking for user name and password. after that terminal.sh file is running in background so its take username and password from myscript.sh file.

Comment: There's two problems. One, scripts have their variables for the duration of their process existence; so once `myscript.sh` exited, variables are gone. Second,  it is  not a secure way  because passing password and username as variables  makes them appear in process list such as `ps` or `top`, so an attacker wouldn't need  to even care about network connection - they'll just read your process list.    So whatever you're trying to do, it's not the best idea.

Comment: As for `ssh -X` and the fact that you're trying to start `xfce` session, that tells me you're trying to launch a GUI via `ssh`.  GUI is done in such way that you *have* to type in password. Where with command-line `ssh` can accept username and password from one computer to the other, GUI gives you graphical prompt. If you can find a solution to this question, that's going to be great, but I think there's a low chance for that.

Comment: my script is working if i am doing all process in xterm but i want uservar and passvar value in terminal.sh script. if you can help me to do this then it is good for me.